# Possible to connect 3.5mm jack microphone on Dell Inspiron 15-5542?

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

I want to confirm that my laptop's *headset* output plug (3.5 mm) can work as an input also but I'm having hard time finding reliable information online, and my preliminary tests show no success.

The laptop's model is `Dell Inspiron 15-5542` running on Windows 10.

When I connect anything to the plug the Dell driver asks what I am connecting:
[image]

The aim? I want to connect a cassette player for digitizing some material.

Comment: It is very unlikely that a audio output will also function as an audio input port.

Comment: Yes it's possible if this is a combo port which dell is putting on their newer laptops. Looks like the first option is for auxiliary like your phone or cassette play, and the second is for microphone.

Comment: @CConard96 I am looking for a way to confirm whether this is a combo port before I start investing in cables, etc.

Comment: Per the user manual, it's a combo port, which includes headphone output and mic input.  However, microphones put out a very low voltage, which must be highly amplified.  A line input is much higher voltage.  Feeding a standard output into a mic input, the amplification will cause a lot of distortion.  Reducing the output volume low enough to not overload the mic input will also be low relative to the output noise.  After amplification, the signal will be noisy.  Use either an adapter that reduces the voltage of the normal output level, or a USB-based input that handles the signal properly.

Comment: @fixer1234 Your answer is perfect (would accept it as such if it was not a comment). Feel stupid now for not searching for the user manual. Will follow your suggestions or simply hire someone to do the digitization for me.

Comment: I've seen a lot of inexpensive USB gadgets advertised to take output from devices like you describe and input it to a PC for digitizing into MP3 or other formats.  BTW, the mic input will be monaural, so you would need something like a USB gadget if you want to preserve stereo sound.

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry to abuse the comment section with a question. But would you know how the 3.5 mm end of my cable should look like for either connecting into the combo plug or the USB gadget? I've seen jacks with 1, 2, and 3 stripes. My suspicion is that I should get one with only one strip on the "bottom" position.

Comment: Info on the jack: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-3-5-mm-jack-in-mobiles-and-laptops.  To use the combo jack, an adapter like this would split out the mic input: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/962633-REG/startech_muyhsmff_3_5mm_4_position_to.html.  A USB adapter would be something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Griffin-Technology-iMic-original-Adapter/dp/B003Y5D776.  You would use a standard cable to connect whatever the cassette output connection is to whatever the USB adapter input connection is (sometimes 3.5mm, sometimes RCA).